# how to add folder to wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress . I have a dashboard wordpress which I got after login. now I have a folder of another website (made with wordpress) which I wish to see in Dashboard.

how to add folder to dashboard?

Comment: What do you mean by a "folder of coding" ? Is it a custom post type on the other website ?

Comment: means a folder which contain coding of another website.

Comment: You want to see an entire other wordpress site in the dashboard?

Comment: yes   @ProEvilz I want to see other website in my dashboard

Comment: @Goli Not possible.

Comment: then how to see that other website in dashboard any other way. @ProEvilz

Comment: You can't in the manner you're describing. Not without a fair bit of work. This is too broad of a question and you're not asking a specific code problem so close this question.